# Prolog, Sorting facts by parameter

Tags: sorting, prolog

I've been trying to find how I could do this, I'm trying to sort facts like:
package(X,Y,N), where N is a number. I want to create a list with the X values, ordered by the value of N (lowest to highest).
Tried using :

gera_caminho_tempo(*,L):- findall(package(N,*,S), package(*,*,S), Packages), msort(Packages, L).

But no results, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such tasks, check out the standard predicate [**`keysort/2`**](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#keysort).

In your case, you can create **pairs** of the form `N-package(X,Y,N)`, using for example:

```
?- findall(N-package(X,Y,N), package(X,Y,N), Pairs0).
```

Once you have obtained `Pairs0`, you can use `keysort/2` to obtain the pairs *sorted by key*, where the first component of each pair acts as its key:

```
?- findall(N-package(X,Y,N), package(X,Y,N), Pairs0),
   keysort(Pairs0, Pairs).
```

I leave relating such sorted pairs to *only* the sorted packages as an easy exercise.